# how to use testrunner.fail in groovy class for soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to fail the test case if string values are not same.I have created a class and a method to compare the string values.

```
public class test1 {
public String onetwo(str1,str2) 
{

    def first = str1
    def second=str2
    if (first==second)
    {
        return "Strings are same"
    }
    else
    {
        testrunner.fail("String Values are not same")
    }
}

public String fail(reason)
{
     return "implementation of method1"+reason
 }
}

def objone =new test1()
def result = objone.onetwo('Soapui','Soapui')
def result1 = objone.onetwo('Soapui','SoapuiPro')
```

while executing it i am getting below message for last line of above code
**ERROR:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testrunner for class: test1**

Please suggest how to use testrunner.fail or any other way to fail the test case if strings are not same.

Thank You

Comment: `testRunner`, with uppercase "R"!

Answer (score 0):

It can't find SoapUI's testrunner because you're accessing it inside your own class. (Note that the error message is trying to find test1.testrunner, which of course does not exist.) If you accessed testrunner from the top level of the script (where you define your variables) it should work.

If you still want to have a reusable class/method, an easy fix would be to have it return a boolean or an error message, and then you call testrunner.fail if your method returns false/error.  Something like this (although a boolean return might make for cleaner code):

```
public class test1 {
    public String onetwo(str1,str2) 
    {

        def first = str1
        def second=str2
        if (first==second)
        {
            return "Strings are same"
        }
        else
        {
            return "String Values are not same"
        }
    }
...
}

def objone =new test1()
def result = objone.onetwo('Soapui','Soapui')
def result1 = objone.onetwo('Soapui','SoapuiPro')

if (result != "Strings are same")
{
    testrunner.fail(result)
}
...
```

[This thread](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=15744) from another site also describes a much more complex solution of making reusable Groovy libraries for SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

If two strings are to be compared in `groovy script` test step, then it is not required to write a class, instead can be achieved with below statement.

**Matching Samples - note that nothing happens on successful assertion**

*String compare and fail if not equal*

`assert 'Soapui' == 'Soapui', "Actual and expected does not match"`

*Another example - with boolen*
`def result = true;assert result, "Result is false"`

**Non-Matching example - test fails on failure**

*Strings not matching, and shows error message*
`assert 'Soapui' == 'SoapuiPro', "Actual and expected does not match"`

*Another example with non zero test*
`def number=0;assert number, "Number is zero"`

If you need only example of the class and like to access `testRunner` object, then we need pass it either to the `class` or to the `method` where testRunner is needed. Otherwise, other class do not know about the objects that are available to groovy script.

**Here is some more information on the objects availability at various level of test case hierarchy.**

When soapUI is started, it initializes certain variables and are available at *Project, Suite, Test case, Setup Script, Teardown script* etc., If you open the script editor you would see the objects available there.

For instance, `groovy script` test step has `log, context, testRunner, testCase` objects. However, if some one creates a class with in Groovy Script test step, those objects are not available with in that user defined class.